# Is there a word for "dating invitation"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for that? Example sentence:

> "He broke the record of the fastest __."

By dating, I mean a "romantic setting." By invitation I mean "asking someone out."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try “for the fastest *come-on*”, which per the OED is:

> 2. A provocation; an enticement; **an invitation**; (now esp.) a sexual advance or invitation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say "... for the fastest pickup." It's somewhat idiomatic but suggests it wasn't hard work.